# Coloring of nodes based on depth from root node

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I have a graph on python using networkx

```
o = net.DiGraph()
hfollowers = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for (twitter_user, followed_by, followers) in twitter_network:
    o.add_edge(twitter_user, followed_by, followers=int(followers))hfollowers[twitter_user] = int(followers)
```

I have a root defined - which is the name of the twitter user

```
SEED = 'BarackObama'
```

I have initialized a subgraph from SEED

```
g = net.DiGraph(net.ego_graph(o, SEED, radius=4))
```

Now, I want to assign color to nodes based on its depth from SEED and plot it. How do I do this ?

Comment: You can use networkx.shortest_path_length(o, SEED) to get a dictionary of all nodes with the length from SEED.  Then use that to color the nodes.

Comment: That helped loads! I had written a program to generate a file having depths. However, I'm not able to find out on documentation on how to set color based on nodes

Comment: Look here for ideas https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/gallery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below I create a graph.  Then I get the distances of each node from that graph.  Then I invert that so that instead for each distance I have a list of nodes at that distance.  Then for each distance I plot the nodes with a given color.  Note that if there is an unreachable node, it won't get plotted.  If such nodes exist you need to decide what you're doing with them separately.

Also because I'm using just the standard colors (except white), I can only do a few distances.  If you need more, then you'll have to use some other way to make your list of colors (or perhaps make a function that returns a color based on distance).  It will take an RGB or HEX definition for a color.

```
G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10,0.4)
G.add_node(11) # here's a new node, it's not connected


SEED=1
distanceDict = nx.shortest_path_length(G, SEED) #for each node know how far it is
inverse_dict = {} #for each distance this will say which nodes are there.
for k,v in distanceDict.iteritems():
    inverse_dict[v] = inverse_dict.get(v,[])
    inverse_dict[v].append(k)
inverse_dict
> {0: [1], 1: [0, 5, 6], 2: [2, 3, 4, 8, 9], 3: [7]}
colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'k', 'c', 'm']#create a list of colors

pos = nx.spring_layout(G) #set positions so that each plot below uses same position
for distance in inverse_dict.keys():
    if distance<=len(colors): #plot these nodes with the right color
        nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos, nodelist = inverse_dict[distance], node_color = colors[distance])


tooFar = []
for node in G.nodes_iter():
    if node not in distanceDict or distanceDict[node]>max_dist:
        tooFar.append(node)
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos=pos, nodelist=tooFar, node_color='w')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do I detect unreacheable nodes ? How do I handle it ?

Comment: code is modified now for this case.  Also note that as I wrote it, it didn't handle nodes beyond a threshold distance (I'd run out of colors).  The code now handles them the same as unreachable nodes.  You could create a longer list of colors instead.